# Java Session Management in multiple tabs of same browser

Tags: java, session, httpsession

I want to allow multiple user login in my application and need to track it through `HttpSession` such that i can manage previously logged in user session even after new session for new user will be created. I am aware, this can be achieved using `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` over `HttpSession`.
But I want to check in same browser (i.e. say Chrome) in multiple tabs How can I have multiple Users logging in into application ?